# openlayers blurred map and window.devicePixelRatio

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm integrating OpenLayers 3 in my webapp.
I found that the map is blurred: I googled around, and I found that this may be related to the fact that, in my PC, the property

```
window.devicePixelRatio
```

is not 1.

This is related to the screen of the PC I develop on. Both in chrome and in firefox these params are not 1, though slightly different one from another.

Looking some websites I find that in most cases this parameter is 1.
So I tried to find what causes this parameter to be != from 1. Well, I found that even the most simple page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
      <p>Asperiores cum debitis eum.</p>
      <p>Minus nihil ullam veniam?</p>
      <p>Beatae ea enim nobis.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

on my PC has windowPixelRatio!==1.

So: what can I do to force my website to have windowPixelRatio===1? This way I can find if this solves the problem of the blurred map.

Comment: well, on stackoverflow itself window.devicePixelRatio is 1 on my PC. I'm wondering how is it possible on websites to force this value.

Comment: I mean, can you demonstrate your code? jsfiddle | plunker

Comment: I got it ! There is something strange in my system. I tried serving the sample page described above from the file system, and it looked smaller.
Serving from nginx it was bigger: so I got 2 different zoom settings while serving from file system and from nginx.

So, for some reasons, although chrome seemed to be zoomed at 100%, it wasn't. It's a known problem that if the browser is not at 100% zoom the map gets blurred.

So I zoomed out to 90%, the zoomed in to 100% back again, and, it solved the problem!

It must be something at the windows level anyway, as firefox got the same problem as well